# Check function for multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have implemented a check function for a project which has 6 input fields, restricted with a function to use only 1 character and only numbers and I want to validate answers entered in these fields. I have created an array with correct answers but it doesn't work like I expected. What I want is to check inputs and store wrong answers to be cleared by reset function. As you can see in fiddle there are 2 feedback images, I need them to be shown when check answers but wrong image for wrong answers and correct image for correct answers. I've been stuck here all day... I couldn't resist and i posted here my problem. Here's some code and a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sDY8c/1/

EDIT: Check function - to compare users answers with array of correct answers.To store wrong answers.To show correct feedback image in the right of input (if correct answers ,show correct image feedback for all inputs with correct answers....if wrong answers,show wrong image feedback for all inputs with wrong answers.

Reset function: - clear feedback image from wrong answers,clean inputs with wrong answers. (NOTE: correct answers after validation will remain with correct answer and correct feedback image)

Thank you!

```
function checkAnswer()
{
    var inputTF = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputTF.length; i++)
    {
        if (inputTF[i].value == raspunsuri[i]){
            user.push(raspunsuri[i]); 

            updateBubble(3);
        }
        else
        {
            user.push("");

            updateBubble(2);

        }
    }

};
```

Comment: From your jsfiddle example, it looks like updateBubble is not defined. I am also confused about your use of init, but never calling that function. Javascript doesn't automagically call a main or init function, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I know...everything works fine except what i said.Init function is called in html on page load...and bubble is a text which must change when i check answers..bubble 1 is text with instruction and bubble 2 and 3 with feedback if user did wrong or right on giving answers in input fields

Comment: Can you make the jsfiddle workable for testing purposes?

Comment: I might be banned if i give a link to download my project? it will be easiest to understand

Comment: No, post which ever link you prefer

Comment: Here it is @Lathan : http://www.fileshare.ro/e30353687

Comment: I have added 3 images of how it must look...is there an image called wrong answers after reset,after reset should look like this image and i must be abble to add another answers.After i add these new answers on check should change upper text again in "Felicitari...." or "Lino este trist..." and little images (green or red) depending on the accuracy of responses

Comment: @Lathan so? did you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there are several significant problems with how you have it currently.

1. You have id="wrong" and id="correct" on 12 different images. An ID must be unique. I suggest you use class="wrong" and class="correct" as classes are meant to be multiples.
2. I added a `user = [];` to checkAnswer, so that it doesn't build up multiple versions of the "correct" answers
3. the .show(...) should be like this: `$(inputTF[i]).nextAll('.correct').show()` or `$(inputTF[i]).nextAll('.wrong').show()` show doesn't take an argument like what you have.

After those 2/3 things are changed, it might work, or I might be able to get a better idea of the issue. When I tested it there were some issues with non-existant sound files, but I commented them out, and my test went fine.

Edit: This is the inner code I used that seemed to work, but I changed all the id="wrong" and id="correct" to be class="feedback wrong" and class="feedback correct" in the html.

```
    if (inputTF[i].value == raspunsuri[i]){
        user.push(raspunsuri[i]); 
        $(inputTF[i]).nextAll('.wrong').hide();
        $(inputTF[i]).nextAll('.correct').show();
        updateBubble(2);
    }
    else
    {
        user.push("");
        $(inputTF[i]).nextAll('.wrong').show();
        $(inputTF[i]).nextAll('.correct').hide();
        updateBubble(3);

    }
```

Comment: Yah,i forgot to comment these audio files...anyway,i made few changes today but didnt finished it :( just 2 things i need.. check function to give me correct bubble and wrong/correct images feedback , store in an array wrong answers to be cleared by reset function.

Comment: I saw i can use on input tag an attribute correct="2" ,maybe it might help?

Comment: you can put a custom html attribute on the input, but I don't think that is part of the problem

Comment: I thoutgh it will be easiest to compare without an array with correct answers :( anyway do you have any ideea?

Comment: Its no problem...i just need it to work,ill understand ur way and ill adapt to it only if works like that ...